# Saving HTML text to a text file with line breaks, spacing, padding and alignment using javascript, jquery or angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

It is possible to save all HTML text in a HTML page to a text file using javascript, jquery or angularjs and retain its format like padding, spacing, margin, alignment, line breaks etc.

If not possible what is the other work around to fulfill it?

Thanks in advance

**SAMPLE HTML FILE:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        h2 {
            font-size:18px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>Paragraphs</h2>
                <p class="normal-space">At vero eos et accu<strong>sam</strong> et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <a href="www.github.com">Github</a>
                </p>
                <p class="normal-space">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                </p>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <hr/>
                <h2>Pretty printed table</h2>
                <table id="invoice">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Article</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Taxes</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                Product 1<br />
                                <span style="font-size:0.8em">Contains: 1x Product 1</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" valign="top">6,99&euro;</td>
                        <td align="right" valign="top">7%</td>
                        <td align="right" valign="top">1</td>
                        <td align="right" valign="top">6,99€</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Shipment costs</td>
                        <td align="right">3,25€</td>
                        <td align="right">7%</td>
                        <td align="right">1</td>
                        <td align="right">3,25€</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td colspan="3">to pay: 10,24€</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td colspan="3">Taxes 7%: 0,72€</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <hr/>
                <h2>Lists</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                    <li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                </ul>
                <ol>
                    <li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                    <li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                </ol>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <hr />
                <h2>Column Layout with tables</h2>
                <table class="address">
                    <tr>
                        <th align="left">Invoice Address</th>
                        <th align="left">Shipment Address</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">
                            <p>
                            Mr.<br/>
                            John Doe<br/>
                            Featherstone Street 49<br/>
                            28199 Bremen<br/>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <p>
                            Mr.<br/>
                            John Doe<br/>
                            Featherstone Street 49<br/>
                            28199 Bremen<br/>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a name="#anchor"></a>
                <hr/>
                <h2>Mailto formating</h2>
                <p class="normal-space small">
                    Some Company<br />
                    Some Street 42<br />
                    Somewhere<br />
                    E-Mail: <a href="mailto:test@example.com">Click here</a>
                </p>
                <p>We appreciate your business. And we hope you'll check out our <a href="http://example.com/">new products</a>!</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

[image: Output Part 1]

[image: Output Part 2]

You can see the sample output text file is formatted based on what you can see in the HTML sample file.

Comment: Are you trying to save plain text or HTML?

Comment: no you cannot save styling in text file if styling written on another file.

yes if html has inline styling its depend on the condition would you please share the code so it easy to understand.

Comment: HTML styling is dependent on CSS or the HTML style attribute, therefore your a program would have to know all that stuff to create the text file. PHP can rip pages with `<?php file_put_contents('new_file_name.txt', file_get_contents('page_you_want.html')); ?>`. Of course, that would just be the source code.

Comment: `print();` will print the page, if that helps.

Comment: @guest271314 it is plain text

Comment: I already updated my post with sample HTML code and sample output display

Comment: You already referred to https://github.com/werk85/node-html-to-text, why don't  you go through that one

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to have an output like that without using that library

Comment: use `text()` method to get only text , and then at server side use line by line

Comment: how about the alignments of the text and the paddings?

Answer (score 1):

You can set text content at a `<pre>` element, which preserves formatting, then save the `.textContent` of the element by creating a `Blob URL` using `Blob` and `URL.createObjectURL()`.

```js
const download = document.querySelector("a[download]");
const pre = document.querySelector("pre#download");
const blob = new Blob([pre.textContent], {
               type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'
             });
const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
download.href = blobURL;
download.onclick = () => {
  window.onfocus = e => {
    window.onfocus = null;
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
    if (blob.close) {
      blob.close();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a download="formatted.txt">download text</a>
<pre id="download">
Paragraphs

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Github

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Pretty printed table

    Article Price Taxes Amount Total
                6,99€    7%      1 6,99€
Product 1
Contains: 1x Product 1

Shipment costs 3,25€    7%      1 3,25€
         to pay: 10,24€
                     Taxes 7%: 0,72€ 
Lists

&#x2022;  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd   
   gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
&#x2022;  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd 
   gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

1. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd 
   gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

2. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd 
   gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Column Layout with tables

Invoice Address         Shipment Address

Mr.                     Mr.
John Doe                John Doe
Featherstone Street 49  Featherstone Street 49
28199 Bremen            28199 Bremen

Mailto formating

Some Company
Some Street 42
Somewhere
E-Mail: test@example.com

We appreciate your business. And we hope you'll check out our new products http://example.com/!
</pre>
```

Comment: The text is came from a HTML content. how can I insert that in a <pre> element?

Comment: Compose the text by hand

Comment: How can I compose it?

Answer (score 0):

There are some approaches like dom2pdf or html2pdf wich are able to translate a html file to a pdf document. But all these approaches can only handle some css styles. Most times it works well, sometimes it doesn't ;)

Comment: I need a HTML to TEXT file not html to pdf